# Primefaces addCallbackParam returns empty:false instead of actual object

Tags: json, ajax, primefaces

I am trying to replace RichFaces components jsFunction and Poll with Primefaces' equivalents. Reason for this is that when I add p:dialog to .xhtml page I am getting some errors related to jQuery.

So much for the background.

I created simple bean like as follows:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PollableBean implements Serializable {

@Getter
private List<String> resultOfPolling = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList("abc","def","ghi"));

public CustomResult gimmeData(){
    System.out.println(resultOfPolling);
    List<String> resultButLocal = resultOfPolling;
    PrimeFaces pf = PrimeFaces.current();
    pf.ajax().addCallbackParam("customResult",resultOfPolling);
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addCallbackParam("saved", resultButLocal);    //basic parameter
    String[] sa = new String[]{"na1","na2","na3"};
    int[] ia = {3,4,5};
    CustomResult cr = CustomResult.builder()
            .p1("name")
            .v1(3)
            .va1(ia)
            .pa1(sa)
            .pl1(Arrays.asList(sa))
            .vl1(IntStream.of(ia)
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                )
            .build();
    pf.ajax().addCallbackParam("event.data", cr);
    return cr;         
}    
}
```

CustomResult class definition is this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class CustomResult {
    String p1;
    int v1;
    String[] pa1;
    int[] va1;
    List<String> pl1;
    List<Integer> vl1;
}
```

My page that invokes polling is like bellow:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <h:outputScript name ="js/test.js"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterView.number}" />
        <p:poll interval="10" listener="#{pollableBean.gimmeData()}" oncomplete="myFunc1(xhr,status,args)" />
    </h:form>
    <script>
        myFunc2();
    </script>
</h:body>
```

And here is my problem.
When I check in console what values I am actually receiving, I can see something like this:

```
{saved: {…}, customResult: {…}, event.data: {…}}
customResult:
       empty: false
       __proto__: Object
event.data:
       p1: "name"
       pa1: (3) ["na1", "na2", "na3"]
       pl1: (3) ["na1", "na2", "na3"]
       v1: 3
       va1: (3) [3, 4, 5]
       vl1: (3) [3, 4, 5]
       __proto__: Object
saved:
      empty: false
      __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

In regard to above my question is:
Why am I getting "empty: false" as content for private List ?

I am using Primefaces 6.2

UPDATE1:

As suggested I created another wrapper containing only List and tried to return it like before. I also added List to check whether my problem is only appearing with Strings. 
Results are following:

```
@Getter
private List<String> resultOfPolling = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList("abc","def","ghi"));

private List<Integer> anotherPollRes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public CustomResult gimmeData(){
    System.out.println(resultOfPolling);
    List<String> resultButLocal = resultOfPolling;

    PrimeFaces pf = PrimeFaces.current();
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    pf.ajax().addCallbackParam("customResult",resultOfPolling);
    context.addCallbackParam("saved", resultButLocal);   

    CustomResult cr = prepCR();
    pf.ajax().addCallbackParam("event.data", cr);

    LSWrapper elsw = new LSWrapper();
    pf.ajax().addCallbackParam("default wrapper", elsw);
    LSWrapper lsw = new LSWrapper(resultOfPolling);
    pf.ajax().addCallbackParam("wrapper", lsw);

    pf.ajax().addCallbackParam("another", anotherPollRes);

    return cr;           
}
```

Wrapper class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LSWrapper {

@Getter
@Setter
private List<String> onlyProp = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("abc","def","ghi"));
}
```

Received JSON:

```
another: {empty: true}
customResult: {empty: false}
default wrapper: {onlyProp: Array(3)}
event.data: {pa1: Array(3), p1: "name", pl1: Array(3), va1: Array(3), vl1: Array(3), …}
saved: {empty: false}
wrapper: {onlyProp: Array(3)}
```

UPDATE 2:

Looking into network traffic with Chrome build-in tools gave me following result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[-887312468948943065:-278897396377742194]]></update><extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"saved":{"empty":false},"another":{"empty":true},"default wrapper":{"onlyProp":["abc","def","ghi"]},"wrapper":{"onlyProp":["abc","def","ghi"]},"customResult":{"empty":false},"event.data":{"p1":"name","pa1":["na1","na2","na3"],"pl1":["na1","na2","na3"],"va1":[3,4,5],"vl1":[3,4,5],"v1":3}}</extension></changes></partial-response>
```

I also tried to instatied some local list (with and without initial values) but result is the same, empty:false / empty:true (accordingly).

I even tried this with old version of Primefaces (5.2 iirc) and the same happened. 
Is it possible that this is only my issue ?
Even it is then why the very same list is "ok" when it is returned as a field of POJO?
I am using Glassfish 4.1.

UPDATE 3:
I guess it is expected behaviour after all.
Documentation at:
https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/PrimeFaces.Ajax.html#addCallbackParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-
states that currently supported objects are: POJOs, JSONObjects and JSONArrays.

To my knowledge generic classes implementing some interfaces are not POJOs.
And the reason why my CustomResult class was serialized correctly is (in my opinion) that it is plain old java object.

Comment: For the `saved` you don't use PrimeFaces callback and you have the same 'problem', so how is this PrimeFaces related? Have you checked the actual network traffic? And how is `customResult` related?

Comment: To me it looks like the PrimeFaces JSON serializer is not deserializing `List<String>` properly but it properly did you CustomResult object.  Can you try creating a wrapper object similar to your CustomResult that just contains the List<String> with setters and getters as its only property.

Comment: @Kukeltje `customResult` allows me to check whether `List<String>` can be obtained at all (and it is as we can see from the `event.data` variable returned from server.

Comment: @melloware: `saved` was done via the default RequestContect and not the PF one if I interpreted it correctly in the code above

Comment: So it might also be a deserialization issue. Checking network traffic should show

Comment: @Kukeltje network traffic shows the same what JS variable does.

Comment: Can you try 7.0CR1?

Comment: I'd just like to add that i spent some time figuring why i got same problem, and it was because i called "onsuccess" event instead of "oncomplete"